# Serialize recursive objects with jackson up to a certain depth

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, gson

I have a tree object structure that I need to Serialize and I want to be able to control the depth of the serialization every time based on a parameter using jackson (or any other library - I am open).

My class is like this:

```
class Node {
    ...
    private String id;
    private Node child;
    ...
}
```

And here are 2 examples of serialized json that I would like to get based on depth level

depth level set to 3

```
{
  "id": "A",
  "child": {
    "id": "B",
    "child": {
      "id": "C",
      "child": {}
    }
  }
}
```

depth level set to 2

```
{
  "id": "A",
  "child": {
    "id": "B",
    "child": {}
  }
}
```

Is there any way to control the depth of serialization in recursive objects?

Thanks

Comment: I would like to clarify that question, you use `deserialization` word but desired output you represent as `JSON`. `Deserialisation` is used when we want to parse `JSON` payload and build `POJO` objects in runtime. From other side, serialisation is a process where we want to create `JSON` payload from given `POJO` structure. So, do you want to deserialise `JSON` with max depth or generate `JSON` with max depth?

Comment: My bad, I want to serialise. I have fixed my question wording. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement custom serializer in which you need to count number of already handled `Node` objects. For each serialization process we need to provide `max depth` value and decrement it every time `Node` class is spotted. Example implementation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Node nodeD = new Node("D", null);
        Node nodeC = new Node("C", nodeD);
        Node nodeB = new Node("B", nodeC);
        Node nodeA = new Node("A", nodeB);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println("Depth: " + i);
            System.out.println(serialiseWithDepth(nodeA, i));
        }
    }

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
            .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            .addModule(createNodeModule())
            .build();

    private static String serialiseWithDepth(Node node, int maxDepth) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerFor(Node.class)
                .withAttribute(NodeDepthBeanSerializer.DEPTH_KEY, new AtomicInteger(maxDepth));

        return writer.writeValueAsString(node);
    }

    private static SimpleModule createNodeModule() {
        SimpleModule nodeModule = new SimpleModule("NodeModule");
        nodeModule.setSerializerModifier(new BeanSerializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
                if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == Node.class) {
                    return new NodeDepthBeanSerializer((BeanSerializerBase) serializer);
                }
                return super.modifySerializer(config, beanDesc, serializer);
            }
        });
        return nodeModule;
    }
}

class NodeDepthBeanSerializer extends BeanSerializer {

    public static final String DEPTH_KEY = "maxDepthSize";

    public NodeDepthBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerBase src) {
        super(src);
    }

    @Override
    protected void serializeFields(Object bean, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        AtomicInteger depth = (AtomicInteger) provider.getAttribute(DEPTH_KEY);
        if (depth.decrementAndGet() >= 0) {
            super.serializeFields(bean, gen, provider);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Depth: 0
Node{id='A', child=Node{id='B', child=Node{id='C', child=Node{id='D', child=null}}}} => 0
{ }
Depth: 1
Node{id='A', child=Node{id='B', child=Node{id='C', child=Node{id='D', child=null}}}} => 1
Node{id='B', child=Node{id='C', child=Node{id='D', child=null}}} => 0
{
  "id" : "A",
  "child" : { }
}
Depth: 2
Node{id='A', child=Node{id='B', child=Node{id='C', child=Node{id='D', child=null}}}} => 2
Node{id='B', child=Node{id='C', child=Node{id='D', child=null}}} => 1
Node{id='C', child=Node{id='D', child=null}} => 0
{
  "id" : "A",
  "child" : {
    "id" : "B",
    "child" : { }
  }
}
Depth: 3
Node{id='A', child=Node{id='B', child=Node{id='C', child=Node{id='D', child=null}}}} => 3
Node{id='B', child=Node{id='C', child=Node{id='D', child=null}}} => 2
Node{id='C', child=Node{id='D', child=null}} => 1
Node{id='D', child=null} => 0
{
  "id" : "A",
  "child" : {
    "id" : "B",
    "child" : {
      "id" : "C",
      "child" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Michal. It seems exactly what I need. In the example code you pasted above did you annotate the Node class with a @JsonSerialize annotation?

Comment: @NikosDim, no it is not required since I used `BeanSerializerModifier` object to register customised serialiser.

Comment: I get the following exception java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase for this code https://codeshare.io/G7jVJr  I am using jackson 2.10.1

Comment: @NikosDim, that's strange. Try to add `getters` to your `Node` class.

Comment: That was it. My bad. Thanks for the help and effort. Really appreciate it.