# Customise Spring Boot Serialisation process with custom jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

A while ago I asked [this question in Stackoverflow](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635711/serialize-recursive-objects-with-jackson-up-to-a-certain-depth) which helped me be build [this spring boot app](https://github.com/NikosDim/spring-boot-custom-serialization/)

At the moment I have created my own object mapper with a `SimpleModule`.
Then using my object mapper I am serializing the `Node` object inside the `Controller` class and I am returning a `ResponseEntity<String>` based on the depth value that is passed in the request parameter.

What I want to achieve is to let Spring Boot do the serialization as it happens normaly. So from inside my `Controller` I want to return `ResponseEntity<Node>` and somehow replace Spring Boots `ObjectMapper` with mine and do the serialization using the depth request parameter.

Any ideas are more than welcomed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this case you probably would have to use `ThreadLocal<AtomicInteger>` to store `depth` value. In controller you need to set it and read and decrement in serialiser.

Comment: But how will force Spring Boot to use my custom Object Mapper?

Comment: Take a look at [Configuring ObjectMapper in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configuring-objectmapper-in-spring)